# Blocking Mongo Driver and codecs Micronaut

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut

I am in the process of creating a new application using Micronaut and MongoDB and I'm experiencing some issues.

At first I went ahead and elected to use the reactive driver but due to some arisen errors I'm refactoring the code to use the blocking one. I have implemented a base interface providing a contract for the db operations as a base MongoDocument class to group together my entities:

```
public interface BaseCrudRepository<T extends BaseMongoDocument> {

    default T save(T document) {
        document.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        getCollection().insertOne(document);
        return document;
    }

    default T findOneAndDelete(Bson filter) {
        return getCollection().findOneAndDelete(filter);
    }

    default Stream<T> list(Bson filter) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(getCollection().find(filter, getType()).spliterator(), false);
    }

    default T findOneUsing(Bson filter) {
        return getCollection().find(filter).first();
    }

    String getCollectionName();

    T delete(T document);

    MongoCollection<T> getCollection();

    Class<T> getType();

}
```

Base mongo document class

```
@Data
public abstract class BaseMongoDocument implements Serializable {

    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

}
```

When I was using the reactive driver I had no problems querying and getting objects from the db mapped to their specific class. Now that I have switched back to the blocking driver I'm getting this error:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class fts.marketing.models.CampaignRun.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.createFindOperation(Operations.java:141)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.find(Operations.java:130)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperations.find(SyncOperations.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.asReadOperation(FindIterableImpl.java:209)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:39)
```

For reference the object I'm trying to save is the following:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@MongoCollection("campaign_run")
public class CampaignRun extends BaseMongoDocument {

    private String merchant;
    private String campaignName;
    private Long runId;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ZonedDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private ZonedDateTime timeScheduled;
    private String lastEmailGenerated;
    private String marketingServer;
    private CampaignRunStatus status;

}
```

I'm trying to understand the error that I'm getting but I can't think of any solution. I am unable to understand why no codec was required when I was using the reactive driver whereas one is required when using the blocking one.

The implementation of the `getCollection` method is actively using the class it's supposed to represent

```
@Override
    public MongoCollection<CampaignRun> getCollection() {
    return mongoClient
        .getDatabase(databaseName)
        .getCollection(getCollectionName(), CampaignRun.class);
    }
```

But for this is not working. I have tried looking online for examples but I did not manage to find any. Can anyone shed some light on this?

**EDIT:**

After a bit of digging around it seems that using the blocking driver will cause Micronaut not to perform any kind of codec related configuration. When using the reactive driver `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` will take care to auto-inject any codecs that it may find as singletons.

This is not the case though for the blocking driver. At the moment, I have no idea how to have a globally unified way of achieving the same behavior with the blocking driver.

Comment: natural way of using mongo in micronaut is via mongo-GORM

Comment: True in case you're developing for Groovy. But when building a Java application using Mongo there is no other way, other than using the client directly.